# Install php_http on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, php, http, curl

First I installed the curl extension for PHP:

```
$ sudo pacman -S php-curl
```

and

```
$ grep curl /etc/php/php.ini
extension=curl.so
```

Then I installed the PHP PEAR

```
$ sudo pacman -S php-pear
```

Having now installed pear, I have also installed PECL, and should now be able to install the php_http extension.

```
$ pecl install php_http
```

and

```
$ grep http.so /etc/php/php.ini
extension=http.so
```

The http.so is found in the folder /usr/lib/php/moduels/ and latter copied to the folder /usr/lib/http/modules/ .

Now, as far as I know, this should have installed the php_http extension, but when I try to

```
$req = new HttpRequest();
```

I get the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /srv/http/webcrawler/nettocrawl.php on line 4
```

Comment: [Looks like](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) HTTP_Request has its own pear package. Is it installed already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PECL HTTP 2.0+

The latest version of pecl_http introduces the http namespace. so `HttpRequest` will no longer be available. Follow php's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for using namespace, and checkout the supplied phpunit directory for usage & examples.

```php
$req = new http\Client\Request();
```

Or a more preferred way, that allows for backwards support

```php
use http\Client\Request as HttpRequest;
$req = new HttpRequest();
```

### Else

Sometimes PECL extensions might not get installed correctly. This can happen if your mixing pacman packages and pecl extensions, but it's very rare. I recommend installing pecl_http by hand.

#### Grab source

```bsh
shell ~> curl -o pecl_http.tar.gz http://pecl.php.net/get/pecl_http
shell ~> tar zvxf pecl_http.tar.gz
shell ~> cd pecl_http
```

#### Configure, Compile, and Test

```bsh
shell ~/pecl_http> phpize
shell ~/pecl_http> ./configure
shell ~/pecl_http> make
shell ~/pecl_http> make test
```

#### Install

```bsh
shell ~/pecl_http> make install
```

This will output the directory `http.so` will be installed. In my case, it's `/usr/lib/php/<timestamp>/`. A helpful note.

#### php.ini & Test

Edit `php.ini` file, and add the `http.so` extension.

```bsh
shell ~> php -m | grep http
```

If `http` is not displayed, re-edit the `php.ini`, and the extensions full path;

```bsh
extension=/usr/lib/php/<timestamp>/http.so
```